# How to effectively monitor change on a remote location?

Tags: java, algorithm, parsing, diff

We have to monitor the change on a remote system file, that we acces throught FTP, SMB.
We do not have any SSH access to the remote system / os. Our only view of the remote system is what FTP or Samba let us see.

**What we do today :**

periodicly scan the whole directory, construct a representation in memory for doing our stuff, and then merge it with what we have in database.

**What we would like to do :**

Being able to determine if the directory have change, and thus if a parsing is needed. Ideally, never have to do a full parsing. We dont want to rely too much on the OS capability ( inodes... )because it could change from a installation to another.

**Main Goal** : This process begin to be slow when the amount of data is very large. Only a few % of this date is new and need to be parsed. How parse and add to our database only this part ?

**The leads we discuss at this moment :**

- Checking the size of folder
- using checksum on file
- Checking the last date of modification of folder / file

**What we really want :**

Some input and best practice, because this problem seams pretty commons, and should have bean already discussed, and we dont want to end up doing something overly complicated on this point.

Thanks in advance, a bunch of fellow developpers ;-)

We use a java/spring/hibernate stack, but i dont think that matters much here.

**Edit** : basicly, we acces a FTP server or equivalent. A local copy is not a option, since the amount of data is way to large.

Comment: Do you need to read the contents of the files to tell if they have changed? You may be able to rely on file size plus modification date together, then you only have to scan the directory listings.

Comment: How do you "directly" access a remote fs, esp. if you don't have "any" access to the remote system?

Comment: @larsmans. The direct acces case is the exception. I have remove it for clarity. What i was willing to express it's we cannot rely on sheel or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

The **Remote Directory Poller for Java** (rdp4j) library can help you out with polling your FTP location and notify you with the following events: file Added/Removed/Modified in a directory. It uses the lastModified date for each file in the directory and compares them with previous poll.

See complete [User Guide](https://github.com/drapostolos/rdp4j/wiki/User-Guide), which contains implementations of the  `FtpDirectory` and  `MyListener` in below quick tutorial of the API:

```
package example

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import com.github.drapostolos.rdp4j.DirectoryPoller;
import com.github.drapostolos.rdp4j.spi.PolledDirectory;

public class FtpExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String host = "ftp.mozilla.org";
        String workingDirectory = "pub/addons";
        String username = "anonymous";
        String password = "anonymous";
        PolledDirectory polledDirectory = new FtpDirectory(host, workingDirectory, username, password);

        DirectoryPoller dp = DirectoryPoller.newBuilder()
        .addPolledDirectory(polledDirectory)
        .addListener(new MyListener())
        .setPollingInterval(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .start();

        TimeUnit.HOURS.sleep(2);

        dp.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: sometime its not working when a remote directory  is modified more than 2 times :( any soln appreciated [see here](https://github.com/drapostolos/rdp4j/issues/4)

Comment: The remote directory is polled and compared with previous poll. If there's been multiple modifications between two polls, it will only been seen as one modification. One solution would be to poll more often (i.e. lower the polling interval to maybe once every minute, or).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use directory sizes or modification dates to tell if subdirectories have changed. Full stop. At a minimum you have to do a full directory listing of the whole tree.

You may be able to avoid reading file contents if you are satisified you can rely on the combination of the modification date and time.

My suggestion is use off-the-shelf software to create a local clone (e.g. rsync, robocopy) then do the comparison/parse on the local clone. The question "is it updated" is then a question for rsync to answer.

Comment: We talk about librairie holding huge amount of data. creating a local copy is not a option, it will take days and it's beyond the disk capacity of the server running ours software.

Comment: You don't say whether you need to parse the file contents, or just know whether it has changed. I assume the latter.

You cannot get a hash without either 
a) reading the whole file over the network, or 
b) installing software on the server.

If you can do b, you have better solutions, like larsman's below. 

Otherwise you are pretty much stuck with modification date and size.

Comment: could you elaborate on why the modification date is not enought to check if something has change is a directory tree ? Thanks.

Comment: @Antoine Claval, If a file is updated this does not necessarily update the timestamp on the parent directory (depending on the method). It will also NOT update the timestamp on the grandparent directory - you cannot look at the grandparent directory and conclude that no file in the tree has changed. Secondly, the timestamp should be set automatically when a file changes but can be reset by applications  - it doesn't require special permission. For example file copy utilities, archive or backup/restore tools use this to set the modification date of copied/restored files to match the original.

Answer (score 2):

As previously mentioned, there is no way you can track directories via FTP or SMB. What you can do is to list all files on the remote server and construct a snapshot that contains:

- for file: name, size and modification date,
- for directory: name and latest modification date among its contents,

Using this information you will be able to determine which directories need to be looked into and which files need to be transferred.

Answer (score 1):

The safe and portable solution is to use a strong hash/checksum such as SHA1 or (preferably) SHA512. The hash can be mapped to whatever representation you want to compute and store. You can use the following [recursive recipe](http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/) (adapted from the Git version control system):

1. The hash of a file is the hash of its contents, disregarding the name;
2. to hash a directory, consider it as a sorted list of filename-hash pairs in a textual representation and hash that.

Maybe prepend `f` to every file and `d` to every directory representation before hashing.

You could also put the directory under version control using Git (or Mercurial, or whatever you like), periodically `git add` everything in it, use `git status` to find out what was updated, and `git commit` the changes.

Comment: @Antoine: the scheme I described is what Git does, which is explicitly designed to track contents rather than files. You can of course adapt it to a scheme where file names are considered part of their contents. (But note that files may have several names; Unix has hard links, Windows has 8.3 and long file names.)